# Vim YouCompleteMe and Ultisnips on Mavericks

Tags: python, vim, ultisnips

I'm having an absolutely HORRIBLE time getting Ultisnips and YouCompleteMe installed on Mavericks. I've brew installed python, then vim. I've got vim mostly working, but there are never ending python errors when trying to enable these two plugins.

Things like:

```
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#bootstrap#Bootstrap:
line   35:
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
```

I've read all I could via google searches, but this fight seems much harder than it did with Mountain Lion.

My .vimrc is here: https://github.com/nobleach/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

I've commented out the two offending plugins for now (and yes, I'm aware I have conflicting bindings, I'm only using one)

Comment: And I assume you are here because you have already used the two plugins issue trackers and their authors/contributors were not able to find a solution?

Comment: Didn't see anything in open or closed issues. Now let's use logic. Post an issue and target the author or a few others that are watching the repo, or target a large audience that may also have seen this problem and can actually be helpful. I certainly do appreciate you taking the time though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that has run into these issues, it's actually the homebrewed python install that has the issue. It needs to be forced to use the brewed openssl verstion:

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
brew uninstall python
brew install python --with-brewed-openssl
```

Should get things moving again.

Comment: You're still getting the same errors that I noted above?

Comment: I get the following error:

Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#bootstrap#Bootstrap:
line   35:
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError no module named UltiSnips

Answer (score 0):

For me, after i upgrade python with homebrew in my mac, i reinstalled the vim to make all the things work.

```
brew uninstall vim
brew install vim
```